# Vapor Swift Fluent : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor

This is my route :

```
router.get("answers","delete", Int.parameter) { req -> Future<Response> in

        let answerID = try req.parameters.next(Int.self)
        guard let _ = getUsername(req) else {
            throw Abort(.unauthorized)
        }
        return Message.query(on: req).filter(\.id == answerID).first().map(to: Response.self) { answer in
            guard let answer = answer else {
                throw Abort(.notFound)
            }
            return answer.delete(on: req).map(to: Response.self) { _ in
                return req.redirect(to: "/answers")
            }
        }
    }
```

But for xCode this is Ambiguous without more context `.filter(\.id == answerID)`

And this is my struct  Message :

```
struct Message: Content, SQLiteUUIDModel, Migration {
var id: UUID?
var username: String
var content: String
var category: String
var question: String
var date: Date
```

}

I don't understand because I use filters on ids in many other routes and it's the first time I show this error.

I googled this and it seems that the errors shows up when Fluent is not imported but I've already `import Fluent` at the top.

Comment: Did you tried with the import of the database of your choice instead? for example: `import FluentMySQL` , or `ìmport FluentPostgreSQL`,...

Comment: Yes `import FluentSQLite`

Comment: Did u recognized you try id (UUID?) with answerID (Int)?

Comment: Oh! You're right! Thanks :-)

Comment: I was indeed missing `import Fluent` in my file ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had time to test your code. If you replace

```
...   .map(to: Response.self) { answer in ....
```

with

```
... .flatMap(to:Response.self) { answer in ...
```

it works.